# Telegram bot forwarding a user's message to a group and sending responses from it?

Tags: bots, telegram, aiogram, telebot

Good afternoon everyone! Recently I started getting acquainted with writing bots for telegrams, I just can’t figure out how to make the bot redirect the user’s message to a specific group, and from there send all the answers back to the chat. I saw somewhere an implementation with the addition of the bot itself to the group, but not the complete code. I will be very grateful for your help.

I saw somewhere an implementation with the addition of the bot itself to the group, but not the complete code.